# Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx$ without using the power rule

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to evaluate $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx$ without using the power rule. I tried using integration by parts but it seems out of luck.

Multiplying both the numerator and denominator with $\sqrt{x}$ we have

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx = \int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} \, dx$$

Integrate by parts: $u = \frac{1}{x}, v' = \sqrt{x}$. We obtain the same integral as above with

$$\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} \, dx = \frac{2}{3} x\sqrt{x} + \frac{2}{3} \int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} \, dx$$

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to do this?

Comment: Why not just check that $2x^{1/2}$ has the correct derivative (e.g., by writing $x^{1/2} = \exp (\frac{1}{2} \log x)$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for $x>0 \ $  with integration by parts
$$u=\frac{1}{x} , \  \ u'=\frac{-1}{x^2} \\ v=\frac{2}{3}x^\frac{3}{2}  \ \ \ \ v'=\sqrt{x}$$
$$ \begin{align} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx =\int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} dx & = \frac{2}{3}x^\frac{3}{2}.\frac{1}{x}-\int  \frac{-1}{x^2}.\frac{2}{3}x^\frac{3}{2} dx +c\\ & = \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{x}+ \int \frac{2}{3}  \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x}  dx +c \end{align} $$
so $$ \Big(1-\frac{2}{3}\Big) \int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} dx  = \frac{2}{3}\sqrt{x}+c  $$
then $$  \int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x} dx = 2 \sqrt{x}+c$$
with power rule
$$ \begin{align} \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx = \int x^\frac{-1}{2}dx &= \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}} x^{1-\frac{1}{2}}+c \\ & =2 \sqrt{x}+c \end{align}$$

Comment: To get from $v'$ to $v$ you have to use the power rule.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x= \sin^2 t$ so that $dx = 2\sin t \cos t \; dt.$  Then

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \; dx = \int \frac{1}{\sin t} 2\sin t \cos t \; dt = 2\int \cos t \; dt$$

$$ =2\sin t + C = 2\sqrt{x} + C.$$

Comment: Good, but no point in using trig sub. here. If you let $x = t^2$ so that $dx = 2t \, dt$ and thus $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2}} 2t \, dt = 2 \int dt$. Take the antiderivative w.r.t $t$ and undo the sub. with $t = \sqrt{x}$ so that $x$ becomes a dummy variable and you will obtain the same result.

Comment: You used the power rule when you computed $dx$ @coshsinh .  I can get my differential through trig identites.

Comment: Good point. I edited my answer to provide an explanation for the differential with a definite integral though.

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \; dx$ without using the power rule

Consider the $u$-substitution formula backwards by treating $u$ as the dummy variable in the integral on the right such that

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\phi(x)}} \; \phi'(x) \; dx = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \; du$$

and if you find the antiderivative on the left with respect to $x$ then you have to undo the substitution with $x = \phi^{-1}(u)$ so that $u$ also becomes a dummy variable.

In this case, we clearly see that by choosing $\phi(u) = u^2$ then the integral on the right greatly simplifies so that we obtain

\begin{align}
  \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\phi(x)}} \; \phi'(x) \; dx & = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}}2x \; dx \\
                                                  & = 2 \int dx                         \\
                                                  & = 2x \Big\vert_{x = \sqrt{u}}       \\
                                                  & = 2\sqrt{u} + C
\end{align}

We eventually have the following result with $x$ as the dummy variable such that

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \; dx = 2\sqrt{x} + C$$

This result is valid on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ because $\phi(u)$ is also continous and bijective on that restriction.

> Note: The integral $\int dx$ is not evaluated with the power rule. If we consider $\int dx$ as the definite integral $\int^x_0 dt$ then we clearly see it corresponds to the summation of all differentials $dt$ from $0$ up to $x$, so that $\int^x_0 dt = x + C$.

Comment: OP will have to comment, but does $\int 1 \ dx = x + C$ also count as a use of the power rule?

Comment: Good observation. If we consider $\int dx$ as the definite integral $\int^x_0 dt$ we can clearly see that it means the summation in the calculus sense of all differentials $dt$ from $0$ up to $x$. I am not sure if this is rigorous enough though.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you are the OP.

Comment: Nevermind, this is something I have not taken into account. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $x = (tan^{4}\theta)$. Now $dx = 4×(tan^{3}\theta)×(sec\theta)^{2}d\theta$. So, your integration will become $$\int [\frac{4×tan^{3}\theta×sec^{2}\theta}{tan^{2}\theta}]d\theta$$ . So, nowbyou can easily evaluate this integral. Substitute $tan\theta = u$ . So, $(sec\theta)^{2}d\theta = du$ . So, the final result of the integration will be $2×\sqrt{x}+C$ .